# Nginx - Direct sub-folder to different server

Tags: nginx, ubuntu-16.04, vhosts

I have a PHP/MySQL website hosted on an Ubuntu 16.04 server, for example on the domain **www.website.com**, and I would like a *"sub-folder"* of that same domain, to be hosted on a separate server.

For example:

> http://www.website.com is hosted on server IP 1.1.1.1

And I would like

> http://www.website.com/another-site/ to be hosted on server IP 2.2.2.2

Both websites are PHP/MySQL, and both servers are Ubuntu 16.04 and I am using Nginx server blocks to manage the domains.

I have had some success with the following set up on 1.1.1.1, but it doesn't seem to work completely and images and css files on the site 404:

```
location /another-site {
    proxy_pass http://2.2.2.2:80;
    proxy_set_header Host another-site.dev;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
}
```

And then on the 2.2.2.2 server:

```
server {
     listen 80;
     server_name another-site.dev;

     root /var/www/another-site;
     index index.php;
     ...
```

Am I on the right lines, or is there a simpler way of achieving this?  I don't want to resort to having both sites on the same server if I can help it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`proxy_pass http://2.2.2.2:80;` requires a slash at the end `proxy_pass http://2.2.2.2:80/;` or it only loads the index.